# ElasticSearch aggregation - get the exact time of a max histogram value in a timeseries

Tags: java, elasticsearch, max, histogram, aggregation

I am quite new to elasticsearch, so apologies if this is a trivial question.

I have a time series with irregular updates every n number of seconds that I want to plot historically.  The data contains a long variable called 'score', and a long variable with the epoch called 'time' for each 'score' as the timestamp.

To reduce the number of points in a long timescale plot (e.g. a whole year), I want to summarize the data in 256 buckets, and use the maximum 'score' value for each bucket; however, I need to retain the original timestamp of each score, and not the beginning of the bucket.

I managed to get the buckets by running the following query:

```js
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/localhost.localdomain/SET_APPS/_search' -d'
{
  "query" : {
    "range" : {
      "time" : {
        "from" : 1429010378445,
        "to" : 1431602378445,
        "include_lower" : true,
        "include_upper" : true
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations" : {
      "time_hist" : {
        "histogram" : {
          "field" : "time",
          "interval" : 10125000,
          "order" : {
            "_count" : "asc"
          },
          "min_doc_count" : 0,
          "extended_bounds" : {
            "min" : 1429010378445,
            "max" : 1431602378445
          }
        },
        "aggregations" : {
          "max_score" : {
            "max" : {
              "field" : "score"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

However, I am only getting the bucket's timestamp, whereas I need the original time of the score:

```js
{
  "took": 8,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 4,
    "failed": 1,
    "failures": [{
      "index": "localhost.localdomain",
      "shard": 2,
      "status": 500,
      "reason
": "QueryPhaseExecutionException[[localhost.localdomain][2]: query[filtered(time:[1429010378445 TO 1431602378445])->cache(_type:SET_APPS)],from[0],size
[10]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: IllegalStateException[unexpected docvalues type NONE for field 'score' (expected one of [S
ORTED_NUMERIC, NUMERIC]). Use UninvertingReader or index with docvalues.]; "
    }]
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2018,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [{
      "_index": "localhost.localdomain",
      "_type": "SET_APPS",
      "_id": "AU09dUBR80Hb_Fungv_r",
      "_score": 1.0,
      "_source": {
        time: 1431255203918,
        score: 6027
      }
    }, {
      "_index": "localhost.localdomain",
      "_type": "SET_APPS",
      "_id": "AU09c7MS80Hb_Fungv_X",
      "_score": 1.0,
      "_source": {
        time: 1431255102221,
        score: 5518,
      }
    } 
        ....
     
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "time_hist": {
      "buckets": [{
        "key": 1429002000000,
        "doc_count": 0,
        "max_score": {
          "value": null
        }
      }, 
         ......
         {
        "key": 1431249750000,
        "doc_count": 215,
        "max_score": {
          "value": 8564.0,
          "value_as_string": "8564.0"
        }
      }, {
        "key": 1431280125000,
        "doc_count": 228,
        "max_score": {
          "value": 18602.0,
          "value_as_string": "18602.0"
        }
      }, {
        "key": 1431259875000,
        "doc_count": 658,
        "max_score": {
          "value": 17996.0,
          "value_as_string": "17996.0"
        }
      }, {
        "key": 1431270000000,
        "doc_count": 917,
        "max_score": {
          "value": 17995.0,
          "value_as_string": "17995.0"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

In the results above, if we query specifically for score 18602, we get the real timestamp:

```js
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/localhost.localdomain/SET_APPS/_search' -d'
{
  "fields": [ "time", "score" ],
  "query" : {
    "term": {
  "score": "18602"
  }
}
}'
{"took":3,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"localhost.localdomain
","_type":"SET_APPS","_id":"AU0-90Vsi-vs_2ajcYu-","_score":1.0,"fields":{"score":[18602],"time":[1431280502124]}}]}}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution:

```js
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/localhost.localdomain/SET_APPS/_search?pretty=true' -d'
{
  "size":0,
  "query" : {
    "constant_score" : {
      "filter" : {
        "range" : {
           "time" : {
             "gte" : 1457868375000,
             "lt"  : 1460460375000
           }
         }
       }
     }
   },
  "aggregations" : {
      "time_hist" : {
        "histogram" : {
          "field" : "time",
          "interval" : 10125000,
          "order" : {
            "_count" : "asc"
          },
          "min_doc_count" : 0,
          "extended_bounds" : {
            "min" : 1429010378445,
            "max" : 1431602378445
          }
        },
        "aggregations" : {
          "max_time": {
            "terms": {
              "field":"time",
              "order" : {
                "max_score": "desc"
              },
              "size":1

            },
            "aggregations":{
              "max_score" : {
                "max" : {
                  "field" : "score"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}' > foo
```

This seems to produce the desired effect:

```js
  
...

"aggregations" : {
    "time_hist" : {
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : 1429002000000,
        "doc_count" : 0,
        "max_time" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [ ]
        }
      }, {
        "key" : 1429012125000,
        "doc_count" : 0,
        "max_time" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [ ]
        }
      },
                   
     ...         
     {
        "key" : 1431249750000,
        "doc_count" : 270,
        "max_time" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : -1,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 269,
          "buckets" : [ {
            "key" : 1431255810484,
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "max_score" : {
              "value" : 8564.0,
              "value_as_string" : "8564.0"
            }
          } ]
        }
      }, {
        "key" : 1431280125000,
        "doc_count" : 285,
        "max_time" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : -1,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 284,
          "buckets" : [ {
            "key" : 1431280502124,
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "max_score" : {
              "value" : 18602.0,
              "value_as_string" : "18602.0"
            }
          } ]
        }
      }, {
        "key" : 1431259875000,
        "doc_count" : 821,
        "max_time" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : -1,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 820,
          "buckets" : [ {
            "key" : 1431269132642,
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "max_score" : {
              "value" : 17996.0,
              "value_as_string" : "17996.0"
            }
          } ]
        }
      }, {
        "key" : 1431270000000,
        "doc_count" : 1155,
        "max_time" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : -1,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 1154,
          "buckets" : [ {
            "key" : 1431278681884,
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "max_score" : {
              "value" : 17995.0,
              "value_as_string" : "17995.0"
            }
          } ]
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the Java code to produce this...

```
public synchronized List<Pair<Long, Long>> 
getScores(Calendar start, Calendar finish, int maxUniqueScoreEntries) 
throws IOException 
{
  List<Pair<Long, Long>> retVal = new ArrayList<>(maxUniqueScoreEntries);
  try
  {
    long startTimeMs = start.getTimeInMillis();
    long finishTimeMs = finish.getTimeInMillis();

    Pair<Long, Long> firstVal = new Pair<Long, Long>(start.getTimeInMillis(), 0L);
    retVal.add(firstVal);

    SearchRequestBuilder srb = client.prepareSearch()
      .setIndices(solutionName)
      .setTypes(ThreadMgrWebSocketsSvc.Subprotocols.SET_APPS.toString())
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("time").from(startTimeMs).to(finishTimeMs))
    .addAggregation(
            AggregationBuilders.histogram("time_hist").minDocCount(0).field("time").order(Order.COUNT_ASC)
              .extendedBounds(startTimeMs, finishTimeMs)
              .interval((finishTimeMs - startTimeMs) / maxUniqueScoreEntries)
              .subAggregation(
                AggregationBuilders.terms("max_time")
                .field("time")
                .order(Terms.Order.aggregation("max_score", false))
                .size(1)
                .subAggregation(
                  AggregationBuilders.max("max_score").field("score"))
              )
          );

      SearchResponse sr = srb.execute().actionGet();

      Histogram timeHist = sr.getAggregations().get("time_hist");
      List<? extends Bucket> timeHistBuckets = timeHist.getBuckets();
      for (int i = 0, len = timeHistBuckets.size(); i < len; i++)
      {
        Long epochTime = null;
        Long maxScore = null;

        Histogram.Bucket maxScoreBucket = timeHistBuckets.get(i);

        Terms maxTimeTermAgg = maxScoreBucket.getAggregations().get("max_time");

        List<Terms.Bucket> buckets = maxTimeTermAgg.getBuckets();

        for (int j = 0, jlen = buckets.size(); j < jlen; j++)
        {
          Terms.Bucket bucket = buckets.get(j);

          epochTime = bucket.getKeyAsNumber().longValue();
          Aggregation agg = bucket.getAggregations().get("max_score");

          if (agg instanceof Max)
          {
            double value = ((Max) agg).getValue();
            if (value > 0)
            {
              maxScore = (long) ((value > 0) ? value : 0);
            }

          }

        }

        if (epochTime != null && maxScore != null)
        {
          System.out.printf(" %d - Date = %s; rawTime = %d ; val = %d\n", i, new DateTime(epochTime).toString(),
          epochTime, maxScore);

          Pair<Long, Long> val = new Pair<>(epochTime, maxScore);
          retVal.add(val);

        }

      }


    System.out.printf("query was %s, %s \n", new DateTime(startTimeMs).toString(),
      new DateTime(finishTimeMs).toString());

    Pair<Long, Long> last = retVal.get(retVal.size() - 1);
    if (last.getSecond().longValue() != finish.getTimeInMillis())
    {
      Pair<Long, Long> endVal = new Pair<Long, Long>(finish.getTimeInMillis(), 0L);
      retVal.add(endVal);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    retVal.add(new Pair<Long, Long>(start.getTimeInMillis(), 0L));
    retVal.add(new Pair<Long, Long>(finish.getTimeInMillis(), 0L));

  }

  Collections.sort(retVal);



  return retVal;
}
```